# Build Avahi without GUI

Tags: build, avahi, make

I'm running Ubuntu Jaunty on a plug computer which I only ever access via SSH.

I want to update Avahi on the device (without GUI) and the only way (that I know of) to get the very latest version is to build from source.

I've downloaded 0.6.30 from the Avahi site, but when I run `./configure` I keep getting hassled for loads and loads of packages that I don't think I need (since I don't want the GUI).

At first I just installed whatever package it complained about and then ran `./configure` again but now it's just getting silly!

Even running with `./configure --disable-qt3 --disable-qt4 --disable-gtk --disable-dbus --disable-mono --disable-monodoc --enable-core-docs` I still get the error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements ( gtk+-3.0 ) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

Which is bizarre because I specified the `--disable-gtk` flag.

So what's going on here? And how can I build Avahi without all the unnecessary (optional) GUI components? There seems to be little -- if any -- documentation available on this.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it with flag `--disable-gtk3`

Answer (score 0):

In case you *do* want to have gtk3, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```